# How to make the holes transparent when copy an outlined text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, outline

I am new to Illustrator. I am trying to reshape part of the Chinese character. When I outline the text and copy part of the character, the holes are always filled.
The original text:

[image]

copy and paste part of the text, it becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make it into a *Compound Path*.

**Right click > Make Compound Path** or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

Make sure the "hole" shapes are in the front.